# Interpretation of an element that belongs to a sum?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $w \in I(u)= \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} J_{i}(u)$.

**My intrepretation :**

If $w \in I(u)$.Then, for $i\in \mathbb{N}^*$ there exists a $w_{i} \in J_{i}(u)$.

Is this interpretation right?

Comment: Can you say where you read this? Perhaps tell us what $u,J_i,I$ are? I don't believe this is standard notation.

Comment: @ancientmathematician. $u$ is a function and $I$ a sum of functionals $J_{i}$, $\forall i $.

Comment: What is your definition of a functional here?  If $J$ is a functional and $u$ is a function, then the statement $w \in J(u)$ isn't meaningful in terms of usual usage of mathematical terminology and symbols

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I thought that, but then if all mathematical objects are sets it does have a meaning ... although not the one the author has in mind (whatever that is).

Comment: @ancientmathematician I would say that for instance, appealing to set theoretic constructions of the real numbers in contexts where functions and functionals are considered, does not fall in the category of "usual usage".

Comment: All math objects can be understood as sets, but there are many ways to view any given object as a set, e.g., many ways to view "two" as a set. To make sense of your question, you first have to specify how you are matching up objects and sets.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $J_{i}(u)= \int_{\Omega} F_{i}(x,u) dx$ where $F_{i}(x,t)= \int_{0}^{t} f_{i}(x,s)ds$

Comment: @hanaachan So again, it doesn't make sense to say that $w \in I(u)$ if $J$ is defined by $I(u) = \int_{\Omega} F(x,u)\,dx$.  Presumably, you have misread something, or the source that you have read from has a typo.  Are you sure that $u$ is a function rather than a **set of** functions?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: you are so right, I wasn't being serious.